# Can not setup contact iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, contract

When I setup information for the contracts in "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" of iTunesConnect, I can not setup the "Contact info". This is because there is no contact showing when selecting the drop-down list as image blow shows. I have even created some users in "Users and Roles".

[image: Contact setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a fairly easy fix. You don't see any contacts in the dropdown, because you haven't created any. To create contracts in iTunes connect, simply press the *Add New Contact* button, fill in the information and press save. This will then allow you to select the created contact in the dropdown.

Hope that helps, Julian